# Link in Material UI and React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

It needs to look like the `<Link`> in Material-UI but the problem is that its doing a refresh when navigating it. So what I did is use the `<Link>` of the react-router-dom and put the `<Link>` of Material-UI as its component.

The problem is with the UI, I wanted to follow the UI of the MUI Link not the react-router-dom. Is there a shorter way without modifying much of its CSS?

```
import { Link as LinkBase } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

      <Link
        component={LinkBase}
        to={`/products/${id}`}
      >
        {name}
      </Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the link of react-router-dom in the components property of the @mui/material

```
import './App.css';

import { Link as LinkBase } from '@mui/material';
import { Link, BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <LinkBase component={Link} to="/home">
              home
            </LinkBase>
          }
        />
        <Route path="/home" element={<h1>a</h1>} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. T think you need read the [MUI guides](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/#global-theme-link), which contains an example for react-router.

@Alexsander Gutierreez's answer is absolutely correct. However, if you want to change the default behavior of all MUI  (contain  link etc...), you can:

```
import RouterLink, {Props as RouterLinkProps} from "@docusaurus/Link";
import {createTheme, LinkProps, ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider} from "@mui/material";

const LinkBehavior = React.forwardRef<
    HTMLAnchorElement,
    Omit<RouterLinkProps, "to"> & { href: RouterLinkProps["to"] }
>((props, ref) => {
    const {href, ...other} = props;
    return <RouterLink ref={ref} to={href} {...other} />;
});

function App() {
    const theme = createTheme({
        components: {
            MuiLink: {
                defaultProps: {
                    component: LinkBehavior,
                } as LinkProps,
            },
            MuiButtonBase: {
                defaultProps: {
                    LinkComponent: LinkBehavior,
                },
            },
            MuiListItemButton: {
                defaultProps: {
                    LinkComponent: LinkBehavior,
                },
            },
            MuiIconButton: {
                defaultProps: {
                    LinkComponent: LinkBehavior,
                },
            },
        },
    });
    
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <SomeChildren/>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Now you will be able to use MUI's `<Link/>` as react-router-dom's `<Link/>` in `<MuiThemeProvider/>`.

```
import {Link} from '@mui/material';

// in <MuiThemeProvider/>
function SomeChildren() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route
                    path="/"
                    element={
                        <Link to="/home">home</Link>
                    }
                />
                <Route path="/home" element={<h1>a</h1>} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```